# Matplotlib: scatter plot with multiple axes with different data lengths and text

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a graph with matplotlib.
On X axis I have volume which goes to 333 ml in 895 lines.
On Y axis I have Absorbance  which goes to 446 ml in 895 lines.
X and Y data are of same length.
Now I want to add fractions names (Fractions) (A1, A2, A3 and so on...) corresponding to the Fraction volumes ml.
The fractions volumes also goes to 333 ml but data points finish in 83 lines.
Also I want to add Temp and Pressure with the same x axis ml but note that they are different data length.

I have attached the excel file with the raw data and attached image of how it should look like.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7r772mqlkpphla/se.xls?dl=0 and:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your data doesn't seem to have conductivity data. To label fractions, I basically iterate over fractions and add label one by one. Here is what I got:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

se_abs_data = pd.read_excel('se.xls', header=0, index_col=0, parse_cols=[0, 1])
se_tube_label = pd.read_excel('se.xls', header=0, index_col=0, parse_cols=[2, 3]).dropna()

# Make a wider figure so that fraction labels are visible.
fig_size = plt.figure().get_size_inches()
fig_size[0] = fig_size[0] * 2
plt.figure(figsize=fig_size)

plt.plot(se_abs_data)

# Find y position for fraction labels
[_, _, ymin, ymax] = plt.axis()
y_tube_label = ymin + (ymax - ymin) * 0.03
# Add fraction labels one by one
for fraction, label in se_tube_label.iterrows():
    plt.text(fraction, y_tube_label, label[0], rotation='vertical', verticalalignment='bottom')
    plt.axvline(fraction, ymax=0.1, color='r')

plt.xlabel('Elution volume (ml)')
plt.ylabel('Absorbance (mAu)')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.legend(['UV1 280nm'], frameon=False)
# plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

Here is the figure:
[image: test.png]

## Edit:

Here is for 2 y axes:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

se_abs_data = pd.read_excel('se.xls', header=0, index_col=0, parse_cols=[0, 1])
se_temp_data = pd.read_excel('se.xls', header=0, index_col=0, parse_cols=[4, 5])
se_tube_label = pd.read_excel('se.xls', header=0, index_col=0, parse_cols=[2, 3]).dropna()

# Make a wider figure so that fraction labels are visible.
fig, ax_abs = plt.subplots()
fig_size = fig.get_size_inches()
fig_size[0] = fig_size[0] * 2
fig.set_size_inches(fig_size)

line_abs, = ax_abs.plot(se_abs_data, color='b')
ax_abs.axis([0, 350, -500, 2500])
ax_temp = ax_abs.twinx()
line_temp, = ax_temp.plot(se_temp_data, color='r')
ax_temp.axis([0, 350, 17.8, 19.6])

# Find y position for fraction labels
[_, _, ymin, ymax] = ax_abs.axis()
y_tube_label = ymin + (ymax - ymin) * 0.03
# Add fraction labels one by one
for fraction, label in se_tube_label.iterrows():
    ax_abs.text(fraction, y_tube_label, label[0], rotation='vertical', verticalalignment='bottom')
    ax_abs.axvline(fraction, ymax=0.1, color='r')

plt.minorticks_on()
plt.xlabel('Elution volume (ml)')
ax_abs.set_ylabel('Absorbance (mAu)')
ax_temp.set_ylabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.legend((line_abs, line_temp), ('UV1 280nm', 'Temp °C'), frameon=False)
fig.tight_layout()
# plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

Here is the figure: 
[image: test.png]

As mention in [matplotlib's How-To](https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#multiple-y-axis-scales): "more than two scales are not currently supported, though it is on the wish list".

Comment: When I run the code with the file I get: 

python se.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "se.py", line 40, in <module>
    plt.plot(se)
NameError: name 'se' is not defined

Comment: @Ziprip Sorry, my mistake. Update it to `se_abs_data` and remove an unused import. Could you please try again?

Comment: Started to work, I have the graph now but the problem is that the fractions overlap with the actual graph. here is the output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f2yffbhzyb7id8d/Screenshot%202017-05-26%2013.42.07.png?dl=0    also, I want to add Temp and Pressure to the same graph and I've updated the xls file with Temp and Pressure values. Note: the data points for Temp and Pressure are again different. How can I plot that?

Comment: @Ziprip Interesting. For reasons I don't understand, it seems that y axis on your plot was set to about `[-100, 2500]`. That brings down the graph and make it overlap with fraction labels. Try add `plt.axis([0, 350, -500, 2500])` right after `plt.plot(se_abs_data)`. That should bring your graph back up and stay away from fraction labels.

Comment: @Ziprip As for adding Temp and Pressure data, I don't know how you want to plot three types of data in one graph with only two y axis... I'm sorry. Maybe open a new question and others can help. If you want dual axis, you can try modify from [this matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html). It's impossible to show you a whole block of new codes in comments. Sorry.

Comment: It did work, axis has shifter upwards. For adding Temp and pressure, I again face the same problem that the data points are different but they go to the same ml value. Should I edit the same question to include Temp and Pressure?

Comment: @Ziprip Updated my answer with two y axes code. As mentioned in [matplotlib's How-To](https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#multiple-y-axis-scales): "more than two scales are not currently supported, though it is on the wish list". That why I don't know how you want to plot three types of data (Abs, Temp and Pressure) in one graph with only two y axis...

Comment: I need help modifying the plot in this thread. I want to break the Y axis between 1000 and 2000. I found a package called brokenaxes on this page github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes but I am unable to use it on the code you wrote. Please help.